# C ncurses: outline multiple characters at once

Tags: c, user-interface, interface, ncurses, curses

Is there an option to apply the `A_STANDOUT` attribute to multiple chars at once? Because the following way is really frustrating:

```
    mvwaddstr(ctrl_win, 1, 2, "W");
    wattroff(ctrl_win, A_STANDOUT);
    mvwaddstr(ctrl_win, 1, 4, "Up");
    wattron(ctrl_win, A_STANDOUT);
    mvwaddstr(ctrl_win, 1, 7, "S");
    wattroff(ctrl_win, A_STANDOUT);
    mvwaddstr(ctrl_win, 1, 9, "Left");
    wattron(ctrl_win, A_STANDOUT);
    // And so on...
```

I need do display the controls for my tui applications and thus this operation is very common. Also I want the info for each button to be aligned with each other, thus it would be convenient to use a single string with '\t' escape character. But in this approach I can't. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can write your own 'write_str' function that interprets control characters however you want:

```
void write_str(WINDOW *win, const char *str) {
    while (*str) {
        switch(*str) {
        case '\t': {
            int y, x;
            getyx(win, y, x);
            x = (x + 8) & -8;  // advance to next tabstop
            wmove(win, y, x);
            break;
        case '\016':
            wattron(win, A_STANDOUT);
            break;
        case '\017':
            wattroff(win, A_STANDOUT);
            break;
        default:
            waddch(win, *str); }
        ++str; }
}
```